# How to prevent multiple event listeners on single object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I need to check if there is an event listener on an `$object` in jQuery mobile. is there a way that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what worked for me was adding events with only using ON and then using [the OFF() method](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove all events when leaving the app-state.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#textDiv").click(function() {
            //Event Handling
        });
        var events = $._data(document.getElementById('textDiv'), "events");
        var eventBound = false;
        if(events != null) {
            var eventBound = true;
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="textDiv">Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, found that solution here before but it doesn't work. (JQ 1.8.2)